# How to change default font in NuxtJS/Vuetify?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Just overwrite the `$body-font-family` like the documentation says doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `nuxt.config.js`:

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true, // IMPORTANT

    ....

    font: {
      family: 'AnotherFont' 
    },
},
```

In `assets/variables.scss`:

```
// Overwrite the default variable
$body-font-family: 'AnotherFont', sans-serif !default;
```

---

If you want to include the Google Fonts locally for offline use:

Install the nuxt/google-fonts module: `npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/google-fonts`

In `nuxt.config.js`:

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/google-fonts'
    
    ...
],

...

vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true, // IMPORTANT

    defaultAssets: false, // Disable the automatic load from online CDN

    ...
},

...

// Download the google fonts
googleFonts: {
   download: true,
   stylePath: 'css/fonts.css',

   families: {
     AnotherFont: true,
   }
}
```

In `assets/variables.scss`:

```
// Overwrite the default variable
$body-font-family: 'AnotherFont', sans-serif !default;
```

I won't link any documentaion page, because this part of the Nuxt documentation is ambiguous and misses several points.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTES**:

- when you disable the loading from the CDN, you lose also the online mdi icons, so you'll need to include them offline too
- if something doesn't work, delete the npm_modules/.cache/nuxt-google-fonts folder (the @nuxtjs/google-fonts module has some bugs)